# Check a dynamic file with specific type in other directory exist or not after got full path to it?

Tags: perl, file, filepath, file-extension

I have a directory(at upper directory of current script execution) with some files inside. Here i have only 1 file type with .log extension, but it's *.log base name is dynamic and will be changed every time script running:

**../ouput/**

```
aaa.txt bbb.txt *.log
```

On this,i want to check the file *.log exist or not, then assign it's full path with file name to a variable for process later. I'm trying with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $dir = getcwd; # Get current directory path into $dir
my $filepath = $dir . '..\\output\\*.log';
# ..\\output\\ to get Upper location and output folder
# assign any "*" base name file with type ".log" to $filepath  
if(-e $filepath ) {
    print("File $filepath exist \n");
}
else
{
    print("File $filepath does not exist \n");
}
```

But i always get $filepath does not exist.
Is there any mistake?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html

Comment: You check if there's a file named `*.log`. And there isn't. To find files matching `*.log`, use `glob`.

Comment: By the way, when `-e` returns false, it doesn't mean the file doesn't exist. It means an error occurred. Only when `$!{ENOENT}` is also true does it mean the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, but i got this error when "use File::Glob::glob()": File::Glob::glob() will disappear in perl 5.30. Use File::Glob::bsd_glob() instead. And this error when "use File::Glob::bsd_glob()": Can't locate File/Glob/bsd_glob.pm in @INC (you may need to install the File::Glob::bsd_glob module)

Comment: You don't need to `use File::Glob`. Perl's [built-in `glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) is just fine.

Comment: *"It worked now. Thanks all"* That isn't sufficient explanation. The *primary purpose* of a page on Stack Overflow is to inform other people of a solution if they have a similar problem. It doesn't help, and it's very selfish, to just bail out once your own problem is fixed. Please write up an *answer* below that describes the resolution and explains in detail what you did to fix the issue.

Comment: Hello Borodin, I already have updated the result in my post. Here i use Glob feature at line 6 and 10.

Comment: So you've changed your question to show code that doesn't have an error? Please don't do that: it makes nonsense of any comments or answers that refer to the original version, and also doesn't make sense in your question: why are you asking for help to fix working code? Please write up an *answer* instead that explains what the problem was and what you have changed. I've rolled back your edit to show the faulty code again.

Comment: Oho, that's my fault. I will add the final code in comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could use perl glob.
Change your script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $dir = getcwd; # Get current directory path into $dir
my $filepath = glob($dir . '/../output/*.log');
# ..\\output\\ to get Upper location and output folder
# assign any "*" base name file with type ".log" to $filepath  
if(-e $filepath ) { 
    print("File $filepath exist \n");
}
else
{
    print("File $filepath does not exist \n");
}
```

It will however ignore all but the first files that match *.log.

Comment: That's what i need to post my result. Thanks you so much :)